# How to defrag Virtual Box HDD files?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, defragment

I am using Virtual Box on Windows 7 Machine. I have created several virtual machines of Ubuntu Servers on it.

I store my all virtual hard drives on a dedicated NTFS partition. This partitions has became too much fragmented. I have defrag it.

I tried O&O defrag 16 Pro Edition and Smart Defrag 3. But none of them succeeded to defrag this partition.

Please tell me any way to defrag the partition where I have large virtual HDD files (About 12-15GB size)

[image]

Comment: One problem you have.  Your partition is 90% full.  If a file is larger then 10% of your partition then it can't be defragmented.  Enlarge the partition.

Comment: @Ramhound 90% fragemented, not 90% full.

Comment: k: drive looks 90% full from the screenshot though.

Comment: Your drive is still nearly full and the reason the fragmented files cannot be moved around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody. I fixed the problem and here is what I did:

I deleted some of my virtual hard drives to get some free space. After that I removed the "compress" attribute on my vhd files.

Finally I run the defragment tool and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you don't have enough free space left on the partition.

> If the fragmented file is bigger than the biggest piece of continuous space available, it is physically not possible to defragment the fragments. You might try to consolidate as much free space as possible by using the SPACE method O&O Defrag offers.

- [REF](http://www.oo-software.com/en/support/faq/oodefrag)

I don't have the program in question so my answer will be based using Defrag.exe on Windows 7/8.

**Steps:**

1. To consolidate free space open an elevated command prompt, and type:

   > Defrag @: /V /U /X

Replace @ with the letter of the partition. "/V" shows fragmentation stats, "/U" shows progress, and "/D" performs a consolidation of free space.

2. To defragment the partition open an elevated command prompt, and type:

   > Defrag @: /V /U /D

Replace @ with the letter of the partition. "/V" shows fragmentation stats, "/U" shows progress, and "/D" performs a defragment.

3. Then run another consolidation.

   > Defrag @: /V /U /X